# If $p(s'|s,a) = 0$, would the reward the reward $r(s,a,s')$ be infinite?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, markov-decision-process, reward-functions, probability-distribution

In chapter 2 of Barto and Sutton's RL book, the four argument probability function $p: S \times R \times S \times A \to [0,1]$ is reduced to three arguments $p: S \times S \times A \to [0,1]$ as follows,
$$ P(s'|s,a) = \sum_{r\in R}p(s',r|s,a) $$
Therefore, the expected rewards for state-action pairs are defined as a two-argument function $r: S \times A \to \mathbb{R} $:
$$ r(s,a) = \sum_{r \in R} r \sum_{s'\in S} p(s',r|s,a) $$

Up to this I understood everything and have no problem. My problem arises when in the next line they defined the expected rewards for state-action-next state triples as $r: S \times A \times S \to \mathbb{R} $ where,

$$ r(s,a,s') = \sum_{r\in R} r \frac{p(s',r|s,a)}{p(s'|s,a)} $$

I do not know how to derive this and it seems very counter-intuitive for me. It is because what if the state $s'$ is unreachable? Meaning there are no arrows in the MDP from s to s' ($p(s′|s,a)=0$). Does it mean that the reward would be infinity? $r(s,a,s′)=\infty$? Or is it undefined for this? As in RL we always try to maximize rewards, taking an infinity reward will always makes it maximum (which makes no sense). It would be very nice if somebody can explain this equation with step-by-step derivation.

Comment: $$ r(s',s,a) = \sum_{r\in R}rp(r|s',s,a) $$. also assume that p(s'|s,a)>0. for conciseness some times notations are simplified. for instance as mentioned in the previous page of the book A is used instead of A(s).

Comment: You're right. I missed that by definition $p(s'|s,a)>0$.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is the equation $r(s', a, s') =\sum_{r \in \mathcal{R}} r \frac{p\left(s^{\prime}, r \mid s, a\right)}{p\left(s^{\prime} \mid s, a\right)}$true?](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/8514/why-is-the-equation-rs-a-s-sum-r-in-mathcalr-r-fracp-lefts-p) It might not be an exact duplicate, but the questions are very similar and it might be a good idea to at least link them.

Comment: yes it does. Many thanks for referring to it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so I was able to find the answer to this question by myself. So I'm sharing it with everyone. By the law of non-exclusive events, $P(A|B) = \frac{P(A,B)}{P(B)}$ where $P(B) > 0$. This can also be written as, $P(A|B,C,D) = \frac{P(A,B|C,D)}{P(B|C,D)}$ (just adding C,D as events that are already happened). In this case we have, $ p(r|s',s,a) = \frac{p(s',r|s,a)}{p(s'|s,a)}$ where by definition $p(s'|s,a) > 0$.

Answer (score 2):

You've correctly figured out the most part of your confusion. The only thing I want to add is that by the *finite* MDP definition here it's certainly possible $p(s'|s,a)=0$ for some $s',s$. The reason you can avoid infinite reward lies in the implicit logic of conditional probability, you cannot arrive at a *definite* posterior updated $P(A|B,C,D)$ via your above equation when you already know $P(B|C,D)=0$. Since the event $B$ here is like a premise or assumption, and if it's already false (no chance to happen) then any derivation based on it can be true, that is, $P(A|B,C,D)$ cannot be definite which certainly is useless for any conceivable application and you have to exclude such priors in deriving expected reward above.